# Nested Parallelstreams - Deadlock. How is it handled?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, deadlock

Writing parallelstreams within another parallel stream is generally not recommended to be a good practice because it can lead to deadlocking scenarios when the outer stream waits for inner one to complete, but it cant because of resource shortage. But Java doesnt really run into this deadlocking scenario provided the user doesnt mention ForkJoinPool threads. If such is not mentioned what is the real limitation ,is it at system level or does JVM implicitly handle this and prevent the deadlocking scenario?

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

numbers.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
    numbers.parallelStream().forEach(j -> {
        System.out.println(i * j);
    });
});
```

In the above code snippet, theoretically speaking parallelstream within another parallelstream can lead to a situation where you exhaust the common ForkJoinPool and it can further lead to the outer parallel stream getting blocked and waiting for the inner parallel stream to complete, but the inner parallel stream can't complete because it can't get a thread from the pool, which is blocked by the outer parallel stream. This form of deadlock is quite hard to replicate given the ForkJoinPool isnt explicitly told to the JVM. I have tried it with different machines and I still end-up getting no such deadlocks even for 1M+ iterations (on both the streams).

Additionally if we specify the forkjoinpool to operate on a set number of threads (lets say parallelism 2). Theoretically speaking, each task in this parallel stream starts another parallel stream and since both the outer and inner parallel streams are trying to use the limited number of threads in the pool, it can lead to a situation where all threads are blocked, waiting for other tasks to complete.

```
public class DeadlockDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(2); // Limited number of threads
 
        forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
            IntStream.range(1, 100).parallel().forEach(i -> {
                System.out.println("Task " + i + " started");
                // Each task starts another parallel stream
                IntStream.range(1, 100).parallel().forEach(j -> {
                    System.out.println("Subtask " + j + " started");
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5); // Simulate some work
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Subtask " + j + " finished");
                });
                System.out.println("Task " + i + " finished");
            })
        );
 
        forkJoinPool.shutdown();
        try {
            forkJoinPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking to understand how is it even getting handled by JVM (at the resource management level).

Comment: What gave you the idea this can run into deadlock?  I wouldn't expect that to happen under any circumstances, and would expect that you can arbitrarily combine parallel streams as long as you don't actually block.

Comment: Hmm. So nesting parallel streams is quite tricky especially when your threads are limited. Let's say you declared a ForkJoinPool of only 2 threads. Then the above could potentially get blocked. Because ur inner stream might actually look for a thread that doesn't exist. Again the example I have put in is very basic. But my real question was mostly how JVM knows how to efficiently handle threads inside nested parallelstreams

Comment: Why would it look for a thread that doesn't exist?  Both of these are simply submitting tasks to the ForkJoinPool's queue, not trying to start threads.  Nothing here is locking up a thread waiting on other tasks' completion.

Comment: Your answers lie in the [Java memory model specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html) especially in section 17.4